# How to inherit from the treenode class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, treenode

I have a class that inherits from TreeNode, called ExtendedTreeNode. To add an object of this type to the treeview is not a problem. But how do I retrieve the object from the treeview?

I have tried this:

```
TreeNode node = tvManual.Find("path/to/node"); // tvManual is a treeview

return ((ExtendedTreeNode)node).Property;
```

But this doesn't work. I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode' to type 'PCK_Web_new.Classes.ExtendedTreeNode'.

What do I have to do to make this work?

------------ SOLUTION -----------------

[Edit] My custom TreeNode class looks like this:

```
public class ExtendedTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    private int _UniqueId;

    public int UniqueId
    {
        set { _UniqueId = value; }
        get { return _UniqueId; }
    }
    public ExtendedTreeNode()
    {
    }
}
```

And this way I add Nodes to my treeview:

```
ExtendedTreeNode TN2 = new ExtendedTreeNode();

TN2.Text = "<span class='Node'>" + doc.Title + "</span>";
TN2.Value = doc.ID.ToString();
TN2.NavigateUrl = "ViewDocument.aspx?id=" + doc.ID + "&doc=general&p=" + parent;
TN2.ImageUrl = "Graphics/algDoc.png";
TN2.ToolTip = doc.Title;
TN2.UniqueId = counter;

tvManual.FindNode(parent).ChildNodes.Add(TN2);
```

And this way I retrieve my ExtendedTreeNode object:

```
TreeNode node = tvManual.Find("path/to/node");
ExtendedTreeNode extNode = node as ExtendedTreeNode;
return extNode.UniqueId;
```

I am using .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: Are all added Nodes of you type ExtendedTreeNode? or do you add regular TreeNode objects as well? Maybe you could show how you are adding them to the TreeView.

Comment: Yes, all Nodes must be of type ExtendedTreeNode

Comment: Somehow (at least in ASP.NET) the `TreeView` converts the inherited `TreeNode`s into `TreeNode`s. I've tried overriding `Clone`, but that didn't help. My extended `TreeNode`s are still turned back into regular ones somehow. I guess I would need to use reflector or something to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following to get all nodes under your parent:

```
TreeNode[] parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Find (parentid, true);
foreach(TreeNode node in parentNode)
{
    ExtendedTreeNode ext_tree_node = node as ExtendedTreeNode;
    if(ext_tree_node != null)
    {
        // Do your work
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do ExtendedTreeNode enode = node as ExtendedTreeNode; enode is always null. How come?

Comment: when using the as casting (called safe casting), if the casting fails, the object is set to null

Comment: Ok, I just looked at how you are adding them. Youll want to change my example from "node as ExtendedTreeNode" to "node.Tag as ExtendedTreeNode". Which brings me to my question, why are you doing that? I think you want to create NT2 and use that (i.e, do not create "TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();"). Then add TN2, not tn, and my original post should work.

Comment: And your ExtendedTreeNode class should start with the following: "public class ExtendedTreeNode : TreeNode"

Answer (score 2):

I found a Microsoft example for how to implement an ASP.NET `TreeView` with tags [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Extend-ASPNET-TreeView-to-93d5d8c5).

Some important steps that are necessary besides just subclassing `TreeNode` and adding a `Tag` property are:

You must subclass `TreeView` and override the `CreateNode` method:

```
public sealed class TaggedTreeView : TreeView {
   protected override TreeNode CreateNode() {
      return new TaggedTreeNode(this, false);
   }
}
```

This prevents the `TreeView` from overwriting your new nodes with `TreeNode`s instead of with your extended type of node.

You will need to have that particular constructor available. (It seems to work using the default constructor, too, but there's a good chance there's a good reason why they used this one.)

```
public sealed class TaggedTreeNode : TreeNode {
   object _Tag;

   public object Tag { get { return _Tag; } set { _Tag = value; } }

   ...

   protected internal TaggedTreeNode(TreeView owner, bool isRoot)
   : base(owner, isRoot) {
   }
```

In order to use the extended `TreeView` you will need a `Register` line like the following in your markup to import the type:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="MyNamespace" Assembly="MyAssembly" %>

...

<asp:TaggedTreeView ID="taggedTreeView" runat="server" />
```

You must also override `LoadViewState` and `SaveViewState` in your inherited `TreeNode` class:

```
public sealed class TaggedTreeNode : TreeNode {

   ...

   protected override void LoadViewState(object state) {
      var arrState = (object[])state;
      _Tag = arrState[0];
      base.LoadViewState(arrState[1]);
   }

   protected override object SaveViewState() {
      var arrState = new object[2];
      arrState[1] = base.SaveViewState();
      arrState[0] = _Tag;
      return arrState;
   }
```

This allows the `TreeView` to preserve the value of your `Tag` properties between postbacks.

Comment: Why not simply public object Tag { get ; set; }  ?

Comment: @dlchambers Sure, I was probably just copying MS's implementation. You can actually extend `TreeNode` any way you want; adding a `Tag` is just one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're creating the nodes as `ExtendedTreeNode`s.

I've noticed that the XxxView (ListView, TreeView, DataGridView) controls tend to clone things unexpectedly. Have you implemented `ICloneable.Clone ()`?

That may work; TreeNode implements `Clone ()` virtually.

I find it easier, though to implement extended properties using the Tag property of the treenode:

```
TreeNode node = tvManual.Find("path/to/node");
return node.Tag as ExtendedTreeNode;
```

---

I strongly recommend against using `Clone ()`; it's a fragile pattern. Use the Tag property:

```
class ExtendedInfo
{
    string NavigateUrl;
    string ImageUrl;
    int UniqueId;

    // other custom properties go here
}

// ...

void CreateTreeNode ()
{
    TreeNode TN = new TreeNode();

    string parent = "parent";    

    TN.Text = "<span class='Node'>" + doc.Title + "</span>";
    TN.Value = doc.ID.ToString();
    TN.ToolTip = doc.Title;

    ExtendedInfo extInfo = new ExtendedInfo;
    extInfo.NavigateUrl = "ViewDocument.aspx?id=" + doc.ID + "&doc=general&p=" + parent;
    extInfo.ImageUrl = "Graphics/algDoc.png";
    extInfo.UniqueId = counter;

    TN.Tag = extInfo;
}

// ...

ExtendedInfo GetExtendedInfo (TreeNode node)
{
    return node.Tag as ExtendedInfo;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't have implmented ICloneble.Clone() Should I do this? If so, how?

Comment: The Tag property of the TreeNode doesn't exist?

Comment: object TreeNode.Tag does exist in Windows Forms. Not sure about ASP.NET, but why wouldn't it?

Comment: Assuming you have a reasonable copy constructor:

    public override object Clone ()
    {
        return new ExtendedTreeNode (this);
    }

However, Clone () is a very fragile pattern. I strongly recommend looking harder for the .Tag () property.

Comment: Show me your code... What version of .NET are you using? I'm on 3.5 SP1; I don't have docs for 2.0.

Comment: And how (/when) do I call the Clone property?

Comment: I will edit my post. How does the copy constructor looks like?

Comment: The TreeView will call clone. I strongly suspect it's already cloning its nodes, dropping the ExtendedTreeNode part.

Comment: Copy constructors are OOP 101. MyClass (MyClass original) { this.field1 = source.field1; ... }

Remember to copy the TreeNode fields as well.

But really: look harder for the .Tag property. It's definitely in 2.0. What error are you getting?

Remember: you have to add the tag when you create the node:

TreeNode node = new TreeNode (...);
ExtendedTreeNode ext = new ExtendedTreeNode (...);
...
node.Tag = node;

Comment: 'Remember to copy the TreeNode fields as well' So I have to override the properties in my ExtendedTreeNode class? Error .Tag: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: I added more info in my answer.

Comment: Thnx, but the Tag property doesn't exists :-(

Comment: I've also noticed, you're not inheriting from TreeNode?

Comment: No: The extended info doesn't need to inherit from TreeNode: It's contained by a TreeNode.

In your original question, post the code using the Tag property that gives you an error

Comment: Look in the code I added to my answer as to how to use the Tag property. I have to go. Good luck.

Comment: Thnx for yhe help, but it didn't work. I still getting the same error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement