# C#: How to use a custom TreeView object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

If you create a custom `TreeView` and `TreeNode` like this:

```
public class CustomTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    private int customInt;

    public int CustomInt
    {
        get
        {
            return customInt;
        }
        set
        {
            customInt= value;
        }
    }

}

public class CustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override TreeNode CreateNode()
    {
        return new CustomTreeNode();
    }
}
```

How do I use this in code? How in my aspx page can I use this `TreeView`?

Comment: this is like your previous question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438198/c-how-to-inherit-from-the-treenode-class

Comment: No, that was about the treenode. This is how to use a custom treeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either put this code in App_Code or build it in an assembly. Then in the ASPX, you need a @Register directive, which will include the namespace with your new control. In case you put it in App_Code the assembly would be App_Code. Then once it is included, you can create it on the page with the defined tag prefix. Here's what I mean:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="MyBuiltAssembly" Namespace="CustomTreeViewNamespace" TagPrefix="test" %>
```

...

```
<test:CustomTreeView ID="CustomTreeView1" runat="server">
```